# How do you change the point of reference measure?

Tags: vertices, units, measurement

So I want to measure from the corner point which is where the 3D Anchor? is?
The one vertex all the way to the bottom left.
I want to measure from That to the selected bottom vertex..
How do you do this?

[image]

Comment: from the vert at 3D cursor all the way to the bottom **left**? or did u mean bottom right?

Comment: The _Edge Length_ feature in the _Overlays_ doesn't have a reference point from where to measure some overall length. It is only showing the length of each selected edge separately. So if you want the overall distance from one certain vertex to some other, you either have to add all edges inbetween or (if there's no straight connection you could summarize) you have to select those two vertices and press F. This way a single edge connecting them is generated and you can see its length. But you should undo this or delete the edge in order to get rid of unwanted geometry.

Comment: It would be nice if there would be a way to select the end vertex to skip everywhere on that perimeter like measuring a waist.. What if someone has to measure a character waist like for pants? How do people "tape" measure it?